# Set path in Java applet

Tags: java, image, path, applet, awt

How do I draw an image from a file in an applet?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

/*
    <applet code = "DisplayImageExample" width = 500 height = 300>
            <param name = "Image1" value = "one.jpg">
            <param name = "Image2" value = "two.jpg">
    </applet>
*/

public class NewApplet extends Applet
{
    Image img1, img2;

    public void init(){

            img1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("aw.jpg"));
            img2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("sd"));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

            //display an image using drwaImage method of Graphics class.
            g.drawImage(img1, 1,5,this);
            g.drawImage(img2, 100,100,this);
    }

}
```

Am I setting the image path correctly?

Comment: `getParameter` gets the value of an init parameter - is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parameter key names from your applet parameters rather than their actual values:

```
img1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("Image1"));
img2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("Image2"));
```